# How to reinforce a drawer panel that is bending at the handle?

Tags: wood

I have a large pull-out trashcan drawer built into my kitchen counter which is poorly designed. It is essentially a trashcan on rails with two attachment points to the panel where the handle is.

Because the drawer handle is at the very top of the panel, far away from the attachment points to the rail, it is starting to bend the panel outwards because of pulling forces over time. It doesn't help that this is a soft-close drawer which requires more initial force to pull the drawer out.

Is there a simple way to reinforce the panel so that it does not continue to bend further?

[image]

Comment: What is the panel made out of and what is it's thickness?

Comment: That and photos of the opening to demonstrate possible clearance are critical to any good answer.

Comment: Above questions important .. I'd like to see how/why it's "bending" ... that seems odd.  I would expect loose screws to cause it to break away from the sliding brackets but it's hard (for me) to think of a material that would typically be used for a cabinet front that is capable of bending in the short radius you've drawn, unless it's totally soaked or rotten.

Comment: A very thin sheet-metal drawer front _without_ any sort of folds, edges or other structures that would reinforce it or a _very_ soggy particle board drawer front are the only logical reasons this would be bending as drawn. Pictures of the _actual_ drawer front, and some pics of the inside (preferably with the garbage can removed so we can see the structure) would help understanding a lot.

Comment: Another factor here is friction at whatever is supporting the drawer. It might be possible to clean the rails and maybe lubricate them to reduce the force needed to pull out the drawer.

Comment: @crip659 The panel is wood (not sure what kind) and 2cm thick

Comment: Usually 2cm(3/4 inch) thick wood does not bend easily by a person pulling on it.

Comment: Need pictures. a 2cm solid wood panel doesn't bend like that. It must be some kind of low end sheet goods. You'll likely end up wanting to replace the panel.

Answer (score 1):

You could add vertical steel strap to the inside surface of the panel.  Steel is quite rigid and will provide a lot of strength.  A couple 12" long [mending plates](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hardware-Essentials-12-x-1-1-8-in-Zinc-Plated-Mending-Plate-5-Pack-851491-0/203810312) would probably do the job.

Comment: Angle iron would be even more rigid than a flat steel plate. _Why_ this is bending seems to be more critical, though.

Comment: I thought about doing this and putting the 2 mending plates vertically down the two sides. Maybe an X shape would be better though.